# Trying to use phantom.js to login facebook

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to create a script to login into my facebook account, but when I run my script I receive the message that cookies aren’t enabled.
My phantom.js script:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1';
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.loadImages = false;
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
phantom.javascriptEnabled = true;

page.open("http://facebook.com", function(status) {


    if ( status === "success" ) {
        page.evaluate(function() {
              document.querySelector("input[name='email']").value = "x";
              document.querySelector("input[name='pass']").value = "y";
              document.querySelector("#login_form").submit();

              console.log("Login submitted!");
        });
        window.setTimeout(function () {
          page.render('colorwheel.png');
          phantom.exit();
        }, 5000);
   }
});
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: perhaps don't use ie6 as the user agent?

Comment: @Daniel A. White I tried with others user agents and I receive the same error.

Comment: @lolix Do you run PhantomJS with option to save cookies?
--cookies-file=/path/to/cookies.txt specifies the file name to store the persistent Cookies (http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html).

Comment: yes, I am using --cookies-file=/path/to/cookies.txt but nothing written in the file :/ @a-bobkov

Comment: @lolix Your script logins fine into my facebook account and writes cookies into file. I run Phantom 2.1.1 with the following command: phantomjs --cookies-file=cookies.txt fb.js.
I can only suggest you login into https, rather than http. You can also clear PhantomJS browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

All works fine, test it. Your problem was, that you didn't catch the `console.log` message from sandbox, to do it, you need to use `page.onConsoleMessage` callback.

```
function click(sel){var event=document.createEvent('MouseEvents');event.initMouseEvent('click',1,1,window,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null);document.querySelector(sel).dispatchEvent(event);}
var page = require('webpage').create({viewportSize:{width: 1600,height: 900},
settings:{userAgent:'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0',
javascriptEnabled:'true',
loadImages:'false'
}});
// https://github.com/dillbyrne/random-agent-spoofer/blob/master/data/json/useragents.json
page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg, line, source) {
    console.log('console> ' + msg);
};

page.open("http://facebook.com", function(status) {
    if ( status === "success" ) {
        page.evaluate(function(click) {
              document.querySelector("input[name='email']").value = "<login>";
              document.querySelector("input[name='pass']").value = "<pass>";
              document.querySelector("#login_form").submit();
              console.log("Login submitted!");
//          setTimeout(function(){ scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight) },2500);//Scrolling to bottom.
//click("a[someAttr=someVal]")
        },click);
        setTimeout(function () {
          page.render('test.png');
          phantom.exit();
        }, 5000);
   }
});
```